# Set Kendo Grid Inline Edit text color

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is it possible to set the textcolor of kendo grid when edit mode is clicked on "inline" edit?

I know kendo theming can do this somehow, but I would like to set myself if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a CSS style as:

```
#grid tbody .k-input {
    color: red !important;
}
```

For setting the color or the text to `red` while editing.

I use `#grid` to apply the style only to the Grid with `id` equal to `grid` and I use `tbody` to narrow the styling only to the body of the table (preventing other inputs from being formatted).